# Apache Ignite, Spring data and mysql does not work together

Tags: caching, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, ignite

I have published project

https://github.com/armdev/ignite-spring-boot

with Spring data JPA, Mysql and Apache Ignite configuration.

This is Ignite cache configuration

```
@Bean  
    public Ignite igniteInstance() {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        // Setting some custom name for the node.
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("springDataNode");
        // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
        // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data
        // repository.
        CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("FlightCache");
        // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
        ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Flight.class);          
        cfg.setActiveOnStart(true);    
        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);
        return Ignition.start(cfg);
    }
```

Project has 2 API, one works without Ignite, but repository which is configured with Ignite does not work. I do not understand reason.

Comment: No exception, no details what you are actually trying to do. No hint, what you tried to fix your problem. How is anybody supposed to answer this?

Comment: Well, actually your example works on my side. I've added a POST endpoint and it works as expected.  
[https://github.com/symbicator/ignite-spring-boot](https://github.com/symbicator/ignite-spring-boot)  
Please check that there are no other Ignite nodes on the net that conflict with yours.

Comment: Hi , thanks, I will have a look

Comment: when I add new entity, it is start work, but its all do in memory, not store in db and does not fetch from DB

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a [CacheStore](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-cachestore) that will operate on top of the MySQL data source. 
You need to enable [write-through and read-through](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store#section-read-through-and-write-through) behavior as well.